# How to convert <nanos> in rest response to time stamp

Tags: rest

I have a REST service which returns me the result after combining two objects.

But the response is in nanos as below:

```
<confirmdate>
<nanos>636000000</nanos>
</confirmdate>
```

But I need the response as

```
<Confirmdate>
2015-12-03T7:17:40.256
</confirmdate>
```